# detecting powering off in external monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, ubuntu-14.04, productivity, hardware-detection

I use an external monitor using HDMI port connected to my laptop. Is there any way I can detect when the external monitor gets switched off due to external power cut?

I would like to move all my windows automatically to the laptop monitor and carry on while the power comes back and revert back once it comes back online.

Note that its still connected to the HDMI port and hence the output of 
xrandr doesn't change even when the monitor gets switched off.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04

Thanks!

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 345mm x 194mm
   1920x1080      59.9*+
   1680x1050      60.0     59.9  
   1600x1024      60.2  
   1400x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 476mm x 267mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   50.0     59.9  
   1920x1080i     60.1     50.0     60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1280x720       60.0     50.0     59.9  
   1440x576i      50.1  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   1440x480i      60.1     60.1  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   720x576        50.0  
   720x480        60.0     59.9  
   640x480        75.0     60.0     59.9  
   720x400        70.1  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: AFAIK HDMI/DP does not work like DVI. Once they get switched off they will be considered disconnected. I think it's just because vanilla X preserve states for it. You should still see a difference in the xrandr output, unless you are using a HDMI to DVI cable/adapter?

Comment: sorry i don't see any change in the output of xrandr when i switch off the external monitor leaving the hdmi port connected. I am also not using a HDMI to DVI adapter.

Comment: but you see changes once you unplug it from the HDMI port?

Comment: yes, i do see HDMI disconnected

Comment: Hmm that's new to me. Maybe some of the vendors manage to make it work like DVI. In that case I think your best bet will be looking into your monitor's settings